# I can't get output voltage from flip-flop in PSpice

Tags: analog, flipflop, output, input, pspice

I'm simulating a flip-flop in PSpice, but it doesn't show an output voltage.

[image]

This is testing a flip-flop; look at the `Q` output. It shows X (undefine). I don't know if I'm missing anything in PSpice.

Comment: I don't know if this is your  problem, but you are violating the setup time specification on the FF. The D input should be stable 20ns or more before the positive clock edge. If that's not it, maybe you need to set a Vcc.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany Thank you for your comment so much.I dont know how to set Vcc on 74LS74A If you  know can teach me ??

Comment: Did you first try connecting D to something other than clock? There is supposed to be a default Vcc, [this](https://www.pspice.com/how-change-default-digital-powerground-supply) page covers changing it.

Comment: I just try dig clock and get digital logic output 1 0 
and I try vpulse like top post sir

Comment: So it sounds like it is modeling the setup time violation correctly.

Comment: OK. What is it your means "The D input should be stable 20ns" .You try to tell me that i have to set D input TD=20n and TF=20n right ??

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Pspice is modeling the setup time violations. The D input must be stable for at least 20ns before the clock and must hold for at least 0ns after the clock edge according to the datasheet. You should add rise/fall times to those numbers.

The D input needs to come from somewhere other than the clock signal. For example if you connect it to /Q the FF will toggle on each positive clock edge.

If you create a second signal similar to the clock but with a delay of 21ns, or if you delay the clock by 21ns relative to the D  input you should get a reliable 0 or 1 respectively.

Here's the timing diagram in case it's not clear from [here](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Etraylor/ece474/beamer_lectures/tsu_and_th.pdf):

[image]

Comment: I'm understand in this point but i'm still dont get output voltage i will try set Vcc first